# How to get domain zone of the DNS A record using Ansible dig

Tags: ansible, dig

Basically I have a simple server name ( non FQDN ) and im trying to identify in which DNS zone it has A record
We have multiple DNS zones in our environment.

As i cant rely on PTR records im trying to use DIG module to look for a A record with zone name as variable. Once the A record is found, i want to use that zone name. Unfortunately im not able to put all the above together in ansible code

i've tried following

```yaml
- name:
      set_fact: 
        found: "{{found+[ lookup('dig', ('{{ dns_name }}.{{item.1}}'), 'qtype=A' , flat=0)] }}"
        domain: "{{ item.0 }}"
        with_indexed_items:
        - zone1.com
        - zone2.com
        - zone3.com
```

```json
ok: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] => {
    "found": [
        "10.10.10.10",
        "NXDOMAIN",
        "NXDOMAIN"]}
```

This generates the list of items but i dont know how to match these items with the list of zones or how to add the index into this list.

Any help would be very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create a dictionary instead of the list and select valid records with json_query. The play below gives the list of the zones with the valid record

```
- set_fact:
    found: "{{ found|default({})|
               combine({ item: {
                        'rec_a': lookup('dig',
                                        dns_name ~ '.' ~ item,
                                        'qtype=A',
                                        flat=0)}}) }}"
  loop: "{{ zones }}"
- set_fact:
    dns_domains: "{{ found|
                     dict2items|
                     json_query('[?value.rec_a != `NXDOMAIN`].key') }}"
```

Comment: if i understand your code then i would receive list of dns_domains which is exactly what i was looking for. i actually built solution but its not as elegant as yours :)

`- name:
      set_fact: 
        found: "{{found+[ lookup('dig', ('{{ dns_name }}.{{item}}') , 'qtype=A' , flat=0)] }}"
      with_items: '{{ zones }} '
      
    - name: result
      set_fact:
        dns_domain: "{{ item.0 }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ zones }}"
        - "{{ found }}"
      when: item.1 | ipv4`

Vy jste fakt machr !!!